# Function that reads and stores values from configuration file

Tags: c++, parsing, configuration

I'm relatively new to C++ programming and I am just trying to create a function that opens a configuration file, reads each line and column, then stores the values into some array.

So my config file will look like this which simply just stores values:

```
12345    10    20
67890    30    40
...
...
```

What I want to do is open this file, read each line and store the values into an `[i][j]` array. So for the above, it would be stored as:

```
[0][0] = 12345
[0][1] = 10
[0][2] = 20
[1][0] = 67890
[1][1] = 30
[1][2] = 40
```

I have been looking at the `fopen` function to open the file, but when I research on how to store these values how I want (using functions like `fgets`), I keep hitting a wall.

My attempt thus far:

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("configFile.conf","r");
    
    char a[20];
    char b[20];
    char c[20];
        
    fscanf(fp, "%s\t%s\t%s", a, b, c);
    cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
}
```

output:

```
12345    10    20
```

Now I want to just modify this loop through until the end of the file and store the values in an array based off the i'th element.

Comment: [fopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) is just a start, if you know how many rows and columns are there then you can define a 2D `int` array the use [fscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf) to read the file and store then in 2D array, if you dont know then you have to go with [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Comment: If you want a specific answer you will need to provide more specific details than "hitting a wall". Show what you tried and explain what specific error or incorrect behaviour or missing understanding that you may have.

Comment: You can use `fscanf(fileptr,"%[^\n]s",array);` to read the file line by line. Then, you can traverse the array and retrieve ASCII values and use something like `atoi()` to convert to integer.

Comment: updated with example @kaylum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   int i = 0;
   fp = fopen("configFile.conf", "r");

   if(fp == NULL) // To check for errors
   { 
      printf("Error \n");
   }

   char a[20][20]; // Declared a 2D array
   char b[20][20];
   char c[20][20];

   while (fscanf(fp, "%s\t%s\t%s", a[i], b[i], c[i]) != EOF) //fscanf returns EOF if end of file (or an input error) occurs 
   {
      printf("%s  %s   %s\n", a[i], b[i], c[i]);
      i++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

C++ code is :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   int i = 0;
   fp = fopen("configFile.conf", "r");

   if(fp == NULL) // To check for errors
   {
      cout<< "Error" << endl;
   }

   char a[20][20]; // Declared a 2D array
   char b[20][20];
   char c[20][20];

   while (fscanf(fp, "%s\t%s\t%s", a[i], b[i], c[i]) != EOF) //fscanf returns EOF if end of file (or an input error) occurs 
   {
      cout << a[i] << " " << b[i] << " " << c[i] << endl;
      i++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is some confusion, So I included `C` as well `C++` code.